# Separating suffixes using a dictionary

Tags: python, regex, dictionary

I need to separate all possible suffixes (about 1000) from a given word. I am thinking about using a dict.

In doing so I would have suffixes as keys (and some additional information about the suffixes as values needed in the further process). If the longest possible suffix is 4 letters long I would search the dict for all possible combinations. 
For example:
Given a word: 'abcdefg' I would search the dict for 'g','fg','efg' and 'defg'.

I have done some research and haven't found much similar uses of the dict. Could this be a viable solution or am I missing something here? Help much appriciated.

Comment: I don't understand the requirement: you're generating suffixes from strings? How would the code look when using an RE?

Comment: [networkx](http://networkx.lanl.gov/) might be better for searching. I don't understand the regex part, are you just using them for splitting your suffixes?

Comment: I thought about using regex for moment for preprocessing because most of the suffixes can be broken down to smaller chunks... But I did't really express the idea in writing, I will edit it out.

Comment: Are 'suffixes' just increasing letter strings from a static string? If so, you don't need a regex. Are you matching whether a defined suffix is on a string? For 1000 elements, you can use a list or a dict or a set -- just depends what makes your data easier to work with.

Comment: I would search in a reversed order (i.e. 4, 3, 2, 1). Sounds more reasonable to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the suffixes aren't too long, your solution sounds fine -- it's only a few dictionary look-ups per word, and dictionary look-ups are fast.  I don't think any more complex solution (like using a trie) would be worth it here.  For only removing the suffix, you could also use a set instead of a dictionary, but since you need additional information for each suffix, a dictionary seems to be the natural choice.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest (probably not fastest) way would be to find all matches in a list.  With 1000 items, you shouldn't have much trouble with performance.

```
>>> sufx = ['foo', 'bar']
>>> [s for s in sufx if 'bazbar'.endswith(s)]
['bar']
>>>[s for s in sufx if 'bazbaz'.endswith(s)]
[]
>>> [s for s in sufx if 'bazfoo'.endswith(s)]
['foo']
```

Comment: This algorithm would have a worst case of O(n * k) with n being the number of suffixes (`len(sufx)`), and k being the length of the string to test.

Answer (score 1):

See [Time Complexity of a dict](http://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity#dict).  Lookup times for a dict are quite fast (O(1) on average!).  For this implementation, your average time complexity for finding the longest suffix would be O(k^2), with k being the length of your word.  It is k^2 due to the `''.join` operation (a similar O(n) operation like reversed or string slicing would be required, as strings do not support an O(1) appendleft operation).

Simple way of doing it (tested for python 3):

```
>>> from collections import deque
>>> word = "antidisestablishmentarianism"
>>> suffixes = {'ism': 3, 'anism': 6, 'ment': 4, 'arianism': 12}
>>> suffix = deque()
>>> longest = None
>>> for char in reversed(word):
...     suffix.appendleft(char)
...     suf = ''.join(suffix)
...     if suf in suffixes:
...         longest = suf
...
>>> longest
'arianism'
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your usecase correctly.  I guess it is about the fact that you are handling suffixes  and they are hard to detect.

A typical approach (typically in indexing situations) would be to turn your string around and handle the suffix as a prefix.  Then you can do a simple binary search in a sorted list of your reversed suffixes (thus prefixes).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you want to do, you should be using the re module in the standard lib.

Docs are here:

http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#module-re

There's an example regarding adverbs here:

http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#finding-all-adverbs

As for storing them as keys in a dict, seems fine to me. Especially, if you want to do some other processing for words that have the suffixes you care about.